# SearchView is not working properly

Tags: android, searchview

I have a SearchView and a RecyclerView inside my Fragment and i created a `getFilter` method for adding search functionality but my problem is this `SearchView` is not working as it should I'm facing two problem which are explained below

1 - suppose i have a data to be searched something like 
{ String1 , String two, String three } if I enter `s` then I'm getting as result only `String1` means  am getting the result according to last word of my String

please see the image for getting what am trying to explain

[in this image you can see am getting the result according to the last word of my String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWeKC.png)

[in my second image you can see that now am not getting any results (but the String contains what am searching for)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxWzQ.png)

this is how i created the `GetFilter` inside my adapter class

```
 private static class UserFilter extends Filter {

    private final NotesAdapter adapter;

    private final List<Information> originalList;

    private final List<Information> filteredList;

    private UserFilter(NotesAdapter adapter, List<Information> originalList) {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.originalList = new LinkedList<>(originalList);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);

        } else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (final Information user : originalList) {
                if (user.title.contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(user);
                }
            }
        }
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        adapter.filteredUserList.clear();
        adapter.filteredUserList.addAll((ArrayList<Information>) results.values);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } }
```

and this is how am using this method in my fragment

```
   Search_View.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                                           @Override
                                           public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String Text) {

                                               Log.v(""+Text , " searchView TextSubmit" );
                                               Log.d("tag", "notesAdapter=" + notesAdapter);
                                               notesAdapter.getFilter().filter(Text);


                                               return true;
                                           }



                                           @Override
                                           public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                                               Log.v(""+newText , " searchView TextChange" );
                                               Log.d("tag", "notesAdapter=" + notesAdapter);
                                               notesAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                                               return true;

                                           }
                                       });
```

if anybody knows what am doing wrong than please help me , stuck here from yesterday

Comment: Are you sure title attribute is stored in lower case?

Comment: @FilippoB what you mean ? i didnt get you

Comment: You was comparing `user.title` to the lower-case string, but actually `user.title` was not lower case

Comment: yes but am converting it while doing the search ,a m not converting the actual content of it cause its giving me desired results

Comment: I was just pointing you to the error, but I noticed later you have already answered yourself

Comment: oh :D got it , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

got the solution was missing to convert my `user.title` to Lowercase

```
  protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);

        } else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (final Information user : originalList) {
                 if (user.title.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern))  {
                    filteredList.add(user);
                }
            }
        }
```